# Bug ToolBar Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, reportviewer, rdlc

I'm working with a report RDLC with a chart, in my asp.net application. 
Everything was ok, until my ReportViewer toolbar started  this strange behaviour. Every button got a entire row space, then one toolbar becomes five bars with one button each.

I compared my font with a backup made one day before, and I didn't find any change that could cause this. Anybody have a tip?

Comment: This rather broad and has no code or concrete examples.  This doesn't really meet the expecations of asking a question on SO.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, I tried to add an image with the problem, but SO didn't allowed me to do it, because I don't have activities enough. I'll improve my next publications, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with `ReportViewer` , every control was misplaced.

I realized `Report Viewer` was just a table and after investigating I found out that some CSS was overriding the layout.

Solution was to aim specific class or id rather then general tags.

For example this code below will affect the report viewer because it affects all table and headers:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 0 none;
}

th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    border: none 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

And the following would be the safe way, and won't affect the report viewer:

```
#someTableName {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 0 none;
}

#myTableHeader {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    border: none 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```